# Do not apply background-blend-mode until background image loads

Tags: css

I'm using `background-blend-mode: multiply` to display a texture image tinted in different colors. The problem is, until the texture loads, the element briefly shows a bright colored rectangle. How do I avoid this, preferably showing nothing at all until the image loads? The usual tricks of using fallback color (`background: #000 url(image.png)`) don't seem to work because of blend mode.

Comment: Can you add/ use Javascript? If so, you could set the element as `display: none;` and use the `onload` function to change it.

Comment: Does onload even work on background images? I could fiddle with it but at that point I might as well just use pre-tinted images. I was hoping for a CSS solution to this.

Comment: I guess the best option is to use inline (blob) image, which probably ensures that it always renders right away?

Comment: You are right I think that onload isn't going to help sense when a background image is loaded. I have hacked this in the past by having an additional  img element with the same URL and using onload. However, there might be a better way. Could you put up a snippet which demonstrates the problem as what I tried didn't give me a flash in the way you describe.